# optimizing python code - analyze and change list

Tags: python-2.7

As a input I have got such list (number of items could change):

```
b = [0.1, 1, 5, 8, 0.4, 2, 0.3, 0.4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0.1]
```

If two next items in list are int and float then insert to list string "X" after int like that:

```
[0.1, 1, 5, 8, 'X', 0.4, 2, 'X', 0.3, 0.4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'X', 0.1]
```

This is my code, first part checks how many items met this condition and second part adds 'X'.

```
c = 0
for i in range(len(b)):
    if type(b[i]) == float and type(b[i-1]) == int:
        c += 1
st = 0      
while st < c:
    for i in range(len(b)):
        if type(b[i]) == float and type(b[i-1]) == int:
            b.insert(i, "X")
            continue
    st += 1
print b
```

Question is how can I optimize this code?

This is somekind of solution but here I base on length of b list which is changing - bad solution.

```
while True:
    for i in range(0, len(b)):
        if type(b[i]) == float and type(b[i-1]) == int:
            b.insert(i, "ok")
            continue
    break
print b
```

Comment: Optimize for what reason exactly?

Comment: First solution which I proposed iterates thru the list twice.

Comment: Yes and your second one does not. So why not use it? This question dosen't belong to SO

Comment: @s_z_p: You can use your second solution if you just store the indexes in an additional list, iterate those indexes in reverse order after, and insert back into b.  You can see how that works at the end of my answer.

Comment: Also, you don't need a `while True` and `break`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a single pass using a [generator function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), setting a flag each time we get a match so we only yield the same object once:

```
b = [0.1, 1, 5, 8, 0.4, 2, 0.3, 0.4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0.1]

def insert_x(lst):
    # create iterator
    it = iter(lst)
    # set matched to False initial and prev to the first element.
    prev, matched = next(it), False
    # start loop from second element.
    for ele in it:
        if isinstance(prev,  int) and isinstance(ele, float):
            yield prev
            yield "X"
            yield ele
            matched = True
        elif not matched:
            yield prev
        else:
            matched = False
        prev = ele
```

Demo:

```
In [10]: b = [0.1, 1, 5, 8, 0.4, 2, 0.3, 0.4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0.1]

In [11]: b[:] = insert_x(b)

In [12]: b
Out[12]: [0.1, 1, 5, 8, 'X', 0.4, 2, 'X', 0.3, 0.4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'X', 0.1]
```

Doing inserts is expensive, some timings:

```
In [12]: b
Out[12]: [0.1, 1, 5, 8, 'X', 0.4, 2, 'X', 0.3, 0.4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'X', 0.1]

In [13]: from random import choice

In [14]: b = [choice(b) for _ in range(100000)]

In [15]: timeit list(insert_x(b))
10 loops, best of 3: 91.2 ms per loop

In [16]: %%timeit
   ....: indexes = [i for i, pair in enumerate(zip(b, b[1:])) if isinstance(pair[0], int) and isinstance(pair[1], float)]
   ....: c = b[:]
   ....: for i in indexes[::-1]:
   ....:     c.insert(i+1, 'ok')
   ....: 
1 loop, best of 3: 1.5 s per loop

In [17]: timeit b[:]
1000 loops, best of 3: 895 µs per loop

In [6]: indexes = [i for i, pair in enumerate(zip(b, b[1:])) if isinstance(pair[0], int) and isinstance(pair[1], float)]

In [7]: c = b[:] 
In [8]: for i in indexes[::-1]:
   ...:         c.insert(i+1, 'X')
   ...:     

In [9]: c == list(insert_x(b)) # exact same result.
Out[9]: True
```

If you take away the cost of `c = b[:]`, it is still significantly slower. Almost 1.5 seconds vs 91ms.

Comment: @s_z_p, everytime you insert,  you are doing more than just inserting one, you are shifting all the elements after which is obviously very costly.  `b[:] = insert_x(b)` does the same as the insert logic in your accepted answer, just a lot  more effifiently.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, nice write up and great approach.  However, I ran this same test myself using the same random 100,000 element list as you create and my approach ran in 625-640ms pretty consistently.  Where would 1.5s have come from?

Comment: @sberry, I actually ran it again there and it performed even worse, ~2.5s vs ~100ms using python2 and python3. What timings are you getting using my code?

Comment: Running your code it is about 34-43ms so still an order of magnitude faster for the large dataset (which is expected).  I am using jupyter console for py2, and have run mine via cmdline using `python -mtimeit -s "b = ..." "my code here" "and here"` and received very similar results, around 625ms.

Comment: @sberry, if you compare the times, the ratio is roughly the same, the difference is hardware. `625 / 38. * .091 -> ~1.5`.

Comment: Ha, right you are.  I was looking at your time as 9ms, not 90ms.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the proper insertion indexes with the following:

```
indexes = [i for i, pair in enumerate(zip(b, b[1:])) if isinstance(pair[0], int) and isinstance(pair[1], float)]
```

The zip() is just creating pairs of neighboring values.

```
[(0.1, 1), (1, 5), (5, 8), (8, 0.4), (0.4, 2), (2, 0.3), (0.3, 0.4), (0.4, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 0.1)]
```

The enumerate will track the index and value at the index.  You can use the value to compare the types with isinstance and keep only the indexes that match your filter.

For your example this returns `[3, 5, 13]`.  However, you can't simply insert at those locations in order because the indexes will change.

So, you can either:

1. Iterate through indexes and increment the next index by 1, then 2, etc. yielding `[3, 6, 15]`
2. Do the insertions in reverse, inserting 13 first, then 5, then 3.

---

```
>>> for i in indexes[::-1]:
...     b.insert(i+1, 'ok')
...
>>> b
[0.1, 1, 5, 8, 'ok', 0.4, 2, 'ok', 0.3, 0.4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'ok', 0.1]
```

Comment: since you are using `2.7` (according to the tag) you can use `itertools.izip` instead of zip to avoid creating the additional list.